# Include HTML files in a PHP wrapper

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, routes

I don't know how to put this better and tried search some around but I wasn't really sure on what to search either for my situation.

I'm in the unfortunate situation of managing a very old website, that has been passed by the hands of at least 5 webmasters.

The whole site is built of several hundreds of pages, each made of a single .html file; there is no controller logic or anything.

Now I need to implement a couple of scripts globally throughout the site, and I was wondering if there is a quick and dirty way to accomplish this.

I was thinking to encapsulate every request through a sort of rudimental PHP controller that simply read the requested file, require it in the script and render it with the same exact content and URL, but with the necessary scrpts included before the closing `</body>` tag.

Unfortunately I'm quite a novice in this, and I'm afraid also to allowing some bad injection from external sources. What is the best way to achieve something like this? I'm on a linux apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches:

**1) PHP Wrapper**

Along the lines of what you're asking for, you can use your web server redirect all incoming HTML requests to a PHP file that does the following:

1. Takes a reference to the HTML file
2. Opens and reads the file in to a string
3. Makes the changes
4. Outputs the modified content in the response

If you are using a server like Apache `httpd` you can use `mod_redirect` to handle redirection of the requested URL to your PHP file.

This approach is a bit inefficient since for each request the HTML content needs to be read and modified. The approach below of editing the files will be higher performance.

**2) Edit HTML Files**

You can write a script to go through all the `.html` files and programmatically edit them.

One implementation to do this would be to open each file and add some lines at the tome and some others near the bottom. A the top of each file you could add a `require()` for your PHP file:

```
<? php
    require('path/to/myinclude.php');
?>
```

At the bottom of the HTML before the `</body>` tag, call your function in the `myinclude.php` file, for example:

```
....
<?
    my_footer_function();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on your webserver, you may be able to have the PHP interpreter execute for the `.html` extension so you don't have to change file extensions, if that's your wish.

This way, after this edit, you can modify all the behavior in the `my_footer_function()` in all your files simply by changing the one `myinclude.php`.

Comment: I'ts indeed one of the first aproach I came up with, but partially discarded because of the big amount of files to edit. What would you suggest in this matter? I have a very basic hosting, simple ftp and cpanel.

Comment: I've actually done this for several very large static sites. If you have a program do it, I found that it's not a big deal.

Comment: Yes indeed, I could .zip the whole site, download and then work on all files via my editor (ST3) on my machine. But still it looks to me to be lot of effort for something that could be done more quickly and dirtier than that (way, WAY dirtier I'm afraid tho). Any chance of the other way I mentioned above with a PHP file that "encapsulate" all the HTML requests? Or its a total nono?

Comment: Also, if you cannot run an editing script on your host, but have the files locally, you can simply edit locally and have the program or another one programmatically S/FTP the files up to your host.

Comment: An alternative approach is that you may be able to redirect all incoming requests to a PHP file which reads in the HTML file as a string, makes the appropriate edits and outputs the content. This depends on what kind of webserver you are using. For example, on Apache `httpd` you can use `mod_redirect`.

Comment: Thank you, that was my exact tought on a possible way of action, but I've interrupted my attempts in this because I was afraid of possible malicious injections and stuff like that. What would be your advice in this regards?

Comment: You should do proper analysis of anything you want to send as a system call, e.g. open a file. Ideally, your file names would be comprised of a limited, safe character set, e.g. [0-9A-Za-z_-\.]. If so, you can do a regex to ensure the name is safe before attempting to locate / open the file. You can run this check in both the webserver redirect and your PHP.